# Program type already present: android.support.v4.R, this error occurs while generating signed APK

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to generate a signed apk and I am getting the error

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.R
```

I have put multiDexEnabled as true and checked various answers on this issue on StackOverflow but none of them helped me solve this issue. But the app runs fine on emulator.
Edit: I found out that ai.api dependency is causing this error. But I don't know how to resolve it. I tried using `exclude group: 'com.android.support'` from ai.api dependency but the issue still persists.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.
Here's my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.puchotask1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
    }

}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

gradle project file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Change this `multiDexEnabled = true` to this `multiDexEnabled true`.

Comment: But now I am getting this error  Program type already present: android.support.v4.R

Comment: Change this `preDexLibraries = false` to this `preDexLibraries false` as well. However, this will not solve your problem I guess. But you have written it wrongly.

Comment: Yeah, still I am getting this error 'Program type already present: android.support.v4.R'